# Failing to compile forked Github Repo with Jitpack

Tags: android, github, gradle, jitpack

I forked a repo on Github and wanted to build it into my project. I figured [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) would be the easiest way to do this. I followed the instructions perfectly and I still cannot get it to compile.

I noticed in Android Studio that when I expand the "External Libraries" section in the left pane that I can see the repo there. However, when I expand it, not all of the classes are there. Some that are there seem obfuscated. I see the Java package name I would expect, but then I see a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, as the classes. What in the world is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what might be happening here. The Android library I forked had ProGuard enabled. I think that I was trying to compile against a binary built with ProGuard via Jitpack, which I don't think will work.

When you build against github source through JCenter, I am guessing that it is building from source, and not from compiled binaries which is why the problem did not exist until I started using Jitpack and forked the repo. I am not 100% sure about that however.

I won't mark this answer as accepted until I am sure that was the issue.